# Multiple foreign keys or multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm actually stuck on how's better to manage a table creation for a following situation,

let's say i have a table called `descriptions` and tables like `items`, `types`, `choices`

each `item` in `items` or `type` in `types` or `choice` in `choices` could have one or more `description`

let's say table `items` `types` and `choices` has the following table structure (each could have specific column for it's table)

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | NAME | PRICE |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | CAR  | 5     |
+----+------+-------+
| 2  | BUS  | 10    |
+----+------+-------+
```

and table `descriptions` has the following one:

```
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| ID | DESC  | DESC_EN | DESC_RU |
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| 1  | CIAO  | HELLO   | ПРИВЕТ  | // This description have to belong to items
+----+-------+---------+---------+
| 2  | PIZZA | PIZZA   | ПИЦЦА   | // This description have to belong to types
+----+-------+---------+---------+
```

so at this point my doubt is, should i create 3 columns in `descriptions` should i create 3 foreign key for `items` `types` and `choices` or should i create 3 separate tables for descriptions for each table?

Comment: Depends a bit on the set up you want. if you recycle the types, choises and items (so use it multiple times) each their own table with a link to it via foreign key / primary key relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution to the translation problem is to have a table with one row per `id`, `language`, and `description`.

This is handy, particularly for adding a new language.  For a new language, nothing needs to change in the database, other than adding rows to some tables.

Another advantage is that a single table can actually hold the translations for multiple different tables -- so all the translations are in one place.  That can simplify keeping them up-to-date and ensuring consistency across an application.

One disadvantage is that the translation column has a single collation.  That makes it tricky to customize sort-orders (and sometimes comparisons) across languages.  Whether this is an an issue also depends on what languages you envision for your application.  Some languages, such as Arabic and Hebrew are written right-to-left which can introduce other complications.

Comment: but even with one row per `id` `language` `description` how should i connect that row to relative row in another table like `items` or `types` shall i add foreign key for each table the translation could appear?

Comment: @IgorMytyuk . . . You would join on the `item` and use the `item_languages` table when there is a language preference (which might be defaulted).  The primary key would be `item_id`/`language_id` (or at least that combination would be unique).

Comment: so i should create the intersect table for each table i would translate like for `item_language` or if i would translate the `types` i must create the intersect table with key `type_id` / `language_id` right?

Comment: @IgorMytyuk . . . That depends on the approach you want to take.  A single table with all translations is convenient for some purposes, but does not allow good definition of foreign key relationships.  Multiple different tables cause proliferation, but do allow for a cleaner data model.